# Do VHDL for loops only allow incrementing by 1?

Tags: vhdl

The VHDL for loop looks like this e.g:

```
for i in -5 to 5 loop   
  -- Do something 
end loop;
```

Can we only increment by 1 or have a arbitrary step size value?

Comment: Can't mark as duplicate as it is on SO: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20392669/vhdl-for-loop-with-step-size-not-equal-to-1

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The only possibilities available for an index of integer type are to increment by 1:

```
for i in 1 to 10 loop
    ...
end loop
```

...or decrement by 1:

```
for i in 10 downto 1 loop
    ...
end loop
```

You can use other ways of generating the *discrete-range*, such as:

```
for i in Input_Signal'Range
```

As an aside, there's also a `for` ... `generate`, which is similar except that the body of the loop contains concurrent statements, where the body of a `for` ... `loop` contains sequential statements.

Comment: Both statements can iterate over enumeration types, too.

Comment: @Paebbels: Good point.